# D - Convert ubyte[] into char[]

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, d

How to convert a `ubyte[]` array into the corresponding (having the same numeric values of bytes/characters) `char[]` array (without risk of undefined behavior)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `cast(char[]) it`. ubyte and char are the same size and same (lack of) constness, the only difference is the semantics of what the items represent, so the cast is perfectly fine there.